# R - How to read text file into a list?

Tags: r, text

I have the following data frame `dat` and a list `b`:

```
Word = c("FOO", "BAM", "ZIP")
Count = c(7, 6, 2)
dat = data.frame(Word, Count)

b<-c("FOO")
```

I'm creating a third column in `dat` that prints TRUE or FALSE like so:

```
dat<-data.frame(dat$Word,dat$Count, dat$Word %in% b)
colnames(dat)<-c("Word","Count","Condition")
```

This prints:

```
>dat
Word    Count    Condition
FOO      7       TRUE
BAM      6       FALSE
ZIP      2       FALSE
```

So far so good. Now instead of creating `b` manually, I want to read in a newline-separated file into R, and still be able to use the code I wrote above to create the 3 column data frame `dat`.

Here's what I mean:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="FOO\nCAT\nDOG\nFISH\n")
dat<-data.frame(dat$Word,dat$Count, dat$Word %in% df1)
colnames(dat)<-c("Word","Count","Condition")
```

However, this prints:

```
>dat
Word    Count    Condition
FOO      7       FALSE
BAM      6       FALSE
ZIP      2       FALSE
```

Instead of how it worked before. My question: How do I import a file say `words.txt` into `df1` so that the code I wrote above still works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'df1' returns a `data.frame` with column 'V1' as the default naming, So we need to extract that column i.e.

```
data.frame(Word = dat$Word,Count=dat$Count, Condition= dat$Word %in% df1[[1]])
#  Word Count Condition
#1  FOO     7      TRUE
#2  BAM     6     FALSE
#3  ZIP     2     FALSE
```

---

If we need this as a `vector`, we can directly get it with `scan`

```
v1 <- scan(text="FOO\nCAT\nDOG\nFISH\n", what="", quiet=TRUE)
transform(dat, Condition = Word %in% v1) 
#   Word Count Condition
#1  FOO     7      TRUE
#2  BAM     6     FALSE
#3  ZIP     2     FALSE
```

NOTE: A `list` is different from a `vector`.  In a `list`, the elements can be of different types, but in a `vector` all of them are of the same `type`.  Based on the output required, it seems that `vector` is what we are aiming for here.