# How to read text file with newline delimited numbers and store it as numerical vector?

Tags: r

I have a text file `myfile.txt` that looks like this:

```
10
20
30
40
```

I try to load it in `R` using:

```
nums <- read.csv('myfile.txt', header=FALSE);
```

However, this returns a list. What I want is the equivalent of:

```
nums <- c(10, 20, 30, 40);
```

I later have code that does the following:

```
v = sprintf("%d", nums);
```

This works fine when I have the vector version, but when I try to load my data from file, I get the following error:

> Error in sprintf("%d", nums) : unsupported type
>
> Execution halted

Comment: `sprintf("%d", nums$V1)` should work. `nums` is a dataframe and not a vector. See also `?sprintf`: *Only logical, integer, real and character vectors are supported*

Comment: Just do `nums<-unlist(nums)` after reading it in, to turn it into a simple vector

Comment: In all honesty, if you don't know how to go from a list object (which is in fact a data.frame, but never mind the details...) to a vector object, you really need to take a look again at the R basics. PS: `sprintf` returns a character representation. If you want them as character, use `as.character`...

Comment: @JorisMeys, I am by no means an expert in R. I had a specific problem and couldn't find information on how to solve it, thus I thought it we be helpful for me and future readers to ask the question. I immediately got a satisfying response and marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Moreover, I really don't get StackOverflow and its core values. One might say that this question is trivial and that's why it got downvoted, but at the same time there are questions that are as trivial, like how to merge two branches in `git`, yet those questions get hundreds of upvotes. I just don't get it...
And it's funny how my question got downvoted and on hold, while at the same time the accepted answer has 5 upvotes. The SO community basically says that the question cannot be helpful to anyone, yet the top answer somehow managed to provide value. It just doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @IvayloToskov I didn't downvote your question. But your question is literally adressed in the first class of my R introduction courses. My advice was well meant. Please do take the time to get some basic training on R, you're going to be grateful you did. To get an idea about object types in R, take a look at this one : https://www.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r

Comment: @IvayloToskov Also a very good one: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-r . Or the one on Coursera: https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-programming . And if you can't be bothered, at least go through all the examples in one of the many R tutorials mentioned here : https://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html  I can personally recommend this one: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf

Comment: @IvayloToskov Regarding the core values of SO: Most basic questions, like how to merge two branches in git, are on SO for years already and stem from the beginning period. I did vote to close your question, because: a) it's not formulated or answered in such a way that it is useful for others, and b) the problem itself is adressed in about every manual about R. And actually, your problem is adressed in this question already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204680/r-how-to-read-text-file-into-a-list  I do agree that the title is confusing.

Comment: @JorisMeys thank you very much for taking your time to give constructive advice and reason about your actions. I have observed that the SO community is sometimes a bit hostile with people who are inexperienced in certain areas and that's why I reacted that way. Downvoting the question and upvoting the answer still doesn't make sense to me though.
And why are questions getting closed? If they are considered useless, why don't they just get deleted?

Comment: @IvayloToskov Questions that are really spam, are deleted immediately. This question might be deleted at one point, but -as you said yourself- it still contains valid information for you personally. So while I too might be a bit sharp at times, we're not as rude as we might appear ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does nobody use `scan` anymore??

```
> scan("./myfile.txt")
Read 4 items
[1] 10 20 30  4
```

I mistyped the fourth item in the file.

Returns exactly what you wanted:

```
> n = scan("./myfile.txt")
Read 4 items
> identical(n, c(10,20,30,4))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `read.csv`, the output should be a `data.frame`.

If you want to access the column of integers, try `nums[[1]]`.  (With `nums` being the output `read.csv`.)

To convert to a vector, use `unlist(nums)`.